# Postgresql + dplyr: loading bigint as a text column

Tags: r, postgresql, dplyr

I've connected to the database:

```
db = src_postgres(dbname = "a", host = "b", port = 5432, user = 'c', password = 'd')
tab = tbl(db, "table")
```

Then I try to count number of rows in each group:

```
tab %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  tally() %>%
  arrange(desc(n))
```

The result is:

```
         id            n
1     6.014e+18 13529622
2     6.014e+18 10906413
3     6.014e+18  8243263
4     6.011e+18  7472041
5     6.014e+18  7094833
6     6.012e+18  6730177
7     6.011e+18  6236673
8     6.011e+18  5924966
9     6.011e+18  4537380
10    6.011e+18  4393328
```

Is there a way to access `id` column in the text form? (something like `id::TEXT` would do in the database)

Comment: Is the column an int64?

Comment: This column is a _bigint_

Comment: Yes, that's going to cause problems because R has no native 64-bit integer. Best thing to do is file a bug report on the dplyr github so I can think about it.

Comment: Is there any way to make dplyr produce SQL as: `SELECT id::TEXT FROM table;`? If it would be stored as text it's totally fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

You could cast the id column into text within the database:

```
tab %>%
  mutate(id = as.character(id)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  tally() %>%
  arrange(desc(n))
```

Comment: This worked for me. Should be accepted answer since the question explicitly asked for loading it as a character. Would be nice of course if there was an implementation that works with e.g. the `bit64` package.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use:

```
  format(id, scientific = FALSE)
```

Comment: It looks it doesn't work with dplyr. At least when working on the SAL database.
Also, when in pure R it also isn't fully precise:
> format(123456789123456789, scientific = F)
[1] "123456789123456784"

Comment: in your db table which datatype is the ID?

Comment: This column is a bigint.

PS: Please ignore "SAL" in my previous comment. I've typed it by mistake there.

Comment: ok, I think you are looking for for something like `options(scipen=100)` to force the numbers to appear with the fixed notation. My only concern would be about how R stores those values in the data.frame, because in that case you have to import the bigint as text.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking exactly for a way to load this column as a text. When I'm doing it using a query i do that casting this column to TEXT (id::TEXT). But I have no idea how to do that using dplyr, or  is it even possible...